# Network disabled - device not ready 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, network-manager, acer

**Laptop**: Acer V 13
no preinstalled OS. Freshly installed ubuntu 16.04.

At the top right corner, when I click the network manager, no wifi networks are found, and there's a grayed out `device not ready` text instead.

Ethernet cable is working (this is how I'm posting this ...)

I'm in a co working space with many networks and users so I know the problem is on my end.

Below you will find everything I've tried followed by every piece of information I thought might b relevant.

I also [logged](http://pastebin.com/mjAXbyJX) the result of this [script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=13024222#post13024222) which has some additional info, and [tailed syslog](http://pastebin.com/J5a8NAUQ) for a while.

Thanks in advance, you rock! :)

---

**Things I've tried**:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

(No output)

```
sudo service network-manager stop && sudo service network-manager start
```

No output, network icon disappears and reappears from tray

```
$ sudo ifup lo
ifup: interface lo already configured`
```

```
$ sudo ifup enp2s0
Unknown interface enp2s0
```

Using [wicd network manager](https://launchpad.net/wicd). I didn't detect any wireless network with that either. (I'm actually glad it didn't work, seems like a bad idea anyway)

```
sudo service networking restart
```

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

```
sudo echo "blacklist ath10k_pci" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

After rebooting, any reference to wifi was gone from the network manager menu in the tray

```
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gksu libgksu2-0 libglade2-0 python-cairo python-dbus python-gi python-glade2 python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-notify python-wicd wicd-daemon
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bcmwl-kernel-source dkms
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 315 not upgraded.
Need to get 1581 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8278 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 dkms all 2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.1 [66,2 kB]
Get:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8 [1515 kB]
Fetched 1581 kB in 0s (4809 kB/s)            
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 206160 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.1) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-34-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-34-generic
Done.
wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/
depmod....
DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.18~16.04.1+0.8-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver6.bin for module i915_bpo
```

Signed and loaded module wl:

```
$ openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=awesome key/"
$ sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n wl)
$ sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
$ reboot
$ sudo modprobe wl # no error output this time :)
```

Reinstalling some packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms linux-headers-generic
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
$ modprobe -r b43 bcma
$ modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
$ modprobe -r wl
$ modprobe wl
$ reboot
```

---

### **Relevant Info:**

```
$ rfkill list
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

- 

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

- 

```
$ iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

- 

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: 30:65:ec:9a:29:e2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:124 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 32
       serial: c8:ff:28:00:90:51
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-34-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:127 memory:a1000000-a11fffff
```

- 

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0807]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
```

- 

in the next file, I've tried to set `managed=true` and reboot, tho somewhere it got reverted back to `managed=false`

```
$ cat  /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

- 

```
    $ dmesg | grep "\(disabled\|switch\)"
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Using 'eager' FPU context switches.
[    0.000000]   6 disabled
[    0.000000]   7 disabled
[    0.000000]   8 disabled
[    0.000000]   9 disabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.069778] DMAR-IR: x2apic is disabled because BIOS sets x2apic opt out bit.
[    0.237651] pci 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.244497] pci 0000:00:1c.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.245318] pci 0000:00:1c.4: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.246125] pci 0000:00:1c.5: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.248614] pci 0000:00:1f.3: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.249896] pci 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.256218] pci 0000:03:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[    0.937596] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.942695] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    0.970222] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
[    1.103625] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    1.103641] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    1.254041] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[ 1117.284285] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 1117.292227] rtc_cmos 00:03: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[ 1117.292230] r8169 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
```

- 

```
$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:65:ec:9a:29:e2  
          inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26514 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:32858129 (32.8 MB)  TX bytes:2703210 (2.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2379 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2379 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:217304 (217.3 KB)  TX bytes:217304 (217.3 KB)
```

- 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it worked, here's what I did:

Backed up `/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174`
Replaced it with https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174
Rebooted

At this point wifi was completely gone from the network manager menu.
so I restored the original QCA6174 folder, rebooted, and it works now!

Marking as solved.
If anyone knows why this worked I'm very curious ...

Comment: I have no idea why it works, but I can confirm this works on Lenovo Y900-Y17ISK.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and the backup, download from GitHub, restore method worked for me, only slightly different. I think it's important to note, as it could affect others who use this method.

Once I had downloaded the GitHub folder, put it in place and rebooted, everything was fixed; I didn't need to restore. I'm not sure what caused this (since my WiFi had been working fine for ages before this problem, and I can't think of anything that changed), but when I compare the two, I find that the backup was missing a whole load of stuff.

It only contained board.bin, board-2.bin, firmware-4.bin, firmware-6.bin, notice_ath10k_firmware-4.txt and notice_ath10k_firmware-46.txt. This means that 6 folders and a few additional files were missing; files and folders that make up the bulk of QCA6174 (the GitHub version is 32.6MB, my backup was only 3MB).