# Wifi networks device not ready

Tags: wireless, 16.04, network-manager

Im unable to access network indicator because "Device not ready" issue, this problem happened after reverting back to NetworkManager from wicd network manager thanks to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) method.

The odd things is, I could connect to wireless connection, unlike most people that cannot connect through WiFi because of this issue.

Comment: Open the **System monitor**, kill the process `nm-applet`, open a terminal and run `nm-applet` whats the output?

Comment: There is no output, it just show blank

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/810229/network-disabled-device-not-ready-16-04?rq=1

Comment: There is no athk folder in my computer

Comment: No worries. While reverting the process to get back the Network Manager, did you follow this step by step? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

Comment: Yeah, I do. But the problem still persist

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Im unable to access network indicator because "Device not ready" issue, this problem happened after reverting back to NetworkManager from wicd network manager thanks to this method.

Have you tried removing unused package that comes with `wicd` ? If no, consider removing it by running `autoremove` command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't think `autoremove` will solve the problem.

Comment: `sudo service wicd stop` and then `sudo service network-manager restart` also works

Answer (score 33):

You can restart your device as it may solve your problem.
Instead, you can also use try restarting your network services:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Comment: Except this long standing virus of Ubuntu and Linux in general has evolved immunity against that antidote. The restart no longer works