# Wifi connected (during installation) yet wifi "device not ready"

Tags: wireless, 20.04, lubuntu, network-manager, lts

I have an interesting problem. I set up a new Lubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) on an older machine (Lenovo T410i).

During the installation (Lubuntu style via simple grafics interfase (I dont know the correct name)), I added the wifi credentials. Now, as I installed the MATE GUI, I have the regular network manager in the task bar. This shows:
Wi-fi networks
device not ready

Yet, I am connected and can see the traffic on the systems monitor (and write this support request).

The problem: I need to connect to another wifi than the current one, thus I need to be able to change the wifi.

What I have already tried:

- restarting the network-manager and using "autoremove"
  [Wifi networks device not ready](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844746/wifi-networks-device-not-ready)
- replace the QCA6174 folder (do not remember the askubuntu link anymore)
- in "Software & Updates" are no "Additional Drivers" listed
- rebootet several times
- tried to search for wifi-networks via terminal, but the wifi-adapter seems not available.

I expect some driver flaw, but have no idea anymore.

What would you suggest? What information could help?

Jack

----------- update ----------

return on: sudo lshw -c network *(I just removed the IP adress)*

```
 *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 06
       serial: 5c:ff:35:0d:09:d3
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.12-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:28 memory:f2600000-f261ffff memory:f2625000-f2625fff ioport:1820(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:26:c7:4f:77:a4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-73-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=xx.xx.xx.xx latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:32 memory:f2400000-f2401fff
```

return on: lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
return on: 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:2153]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 06)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `lshw -c network` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`? This will show information about your network hardware. I wonder if you’re experiencing the old 802.11n reliability issue that is solved with `11n_disable=1` 

Comment: You lost me when you mention "*I installed the MATE GUI*" as Lubuntu does not come with a MATE GUI. Are you saying you've installed a second desktop on your system? in which case you should specify which desktop you're using and asking about (the Qt or GTK one...)

Comment: Thank you matigo and guiverc for the quick response. Matigo, i updated the initial post. Guiverc, Yes, Lubuntu came without GUI. I wanted to start on this older machine as minimalistic as possible. After the lubuntu installation was successful, I installed MATE as Desktop Environment, which is to my knowledge mostly based on the GTK+ toolkit.
In general, it is a dual boot with Win7, where wifi runs flawlessly. I had on this machine a few years back Ubuntu 12.04 running, where the wifi work also perfectly. Now I just came back to this old machine and replaced the outdated Ubuntu with Lubuntu.

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 LTS comes with the LXQt desktop/GUI so I don't understand "*Lubuntu came without GUI*". If you wanted MATE and to use a GTK3 environment, I'd have just installed Ubuntu-MATE 20.04 LTS rather than start with a Qt5/LXQt (Lubuntu) base system; but the no GUI makes no sense to me.  If it installed without GUI, I'd validate you downloaded from a legitimate site (ie. use https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours to find legit sites as asking google provides 3+ choices for download and only 1 of them is Ubuntu/Lubuntu related and it's usually not first depending on your past search history)

Comment: I would agree. I could not get the Ubuntu live flash drive running on this old PC so I tried Lubuntu (Downloaded from the official site and checked with hash); After installation, I could not start LXQt, thus I decided to install MATE. I hope this helps to find the rootcause of the original issue of the network manager.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fresh install with Ubuntu 20.04 -> problem solved.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu, Lubuntu & Ubuntu-MATE have the same base image, so a fresh install may mean only some of your configurations were different this time (incorrect prior times) OR you've used a different image.  20.04 & 20.04.1 media for Lubuntu/MATE use the GA kernel, but 20.04.2 for Lubuntu/MATE use HWE, where Ubuntu uses HWE stack for all. The GA vs HWE stack is major difference between them, not desktop (GNOME is just heavier than MATE, MATE heavier than LXQt) in my opinion.